# Android java timepicker.getTime() method?

Tags: java, android, date, time

I have the following situation:

```java
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date currenthour= calendar.getTime();

if (currenthour.after(timePicker.getTime()) && currenthour.before(timePicker2.getTime())){
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

It seems that timePicker.getTime() does not exist. Can a getTime() function can 
be created for timePicker? Or is there a simpler method to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way... Be carefull to check also seconds and miliseconds...
Avoid converting time to String!!

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date currenthour= calendar.getTime();

    Calendar calendarTmp = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarTmp.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
    calendarTmp.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    calendarTmp.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (currenthour.after(calendarTmp.getTime()) && currenthour.before(calendarTmp.getTime())){

        //DO SOMETHING
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In **TimePicker** you can get this hour and minute to  Integer variable.
 Like

```
int hour = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
int minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

Comment: calendar.getTime() - gives me time in HH:mm format but the timePicker gives me a hour and then the minutes. How should i manipulate this so i could compare them ? Convert them to strings?

Comment: yes we can Convert them to strings,,,String hh= Integer.toString(hour);

Comment: it is possible instead of calendar.gettime(); to use galendar.HOUR , and calendar.MINUTE and then compare with the timepicker.getCurrentHour and timepicker.getCurrentMinute(); ?